# Find the number of characters from the first character of nth occurrence of a character in a text file without using an array and strchr function?

Tags: c

Fore example lets assume the following is a text in a file:

"I want to find number of characters from the first character is the nth occurrence of a character in a text file, but, I want to do this without declaring an array, storing the text file in it and applying the strchr function."

Lets say I want to find the position of the second new line character in the text? How many number of characters is the new line from the first character in the text? For e.g. The first occurrence character 't' is the 6th character of the text file.

If it is possible can someone please explain how? If no, can someone please explain why?

Comment: Can you use a memory mapped file (POSIX [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html), for example)?  If so, then you can treat it just like an array in memory — that's what it means.  If not, you need to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: For example, lets say I want to find a character in a text file, is it possible to do that without using an array to store text and strchr function? Is it possible I assign a pointer to the first character of the file and use pointer arithmetic to find a particular character?

Comment: It depends on whether you regard the memory mapped file as an array of bytes (a very sensible interpretation).  Given its base address (returned by `mmap()`), you can do pointer arithmetic to access any location in the file. You say "without using an array" — then you need to be more careful.  Judicious use of [`pread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html), for example, might allow you to do the job with no array in the program.  I didn't mention 'efficient' though.

Comment: It feels like there's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here — you're asking about how to do something that doesn't make an awful lot of sense, but you're really trying to solve a different problem (which would make sense) and have started down what is probably the wrong track and are wondering why it doesn't work.  Review the motivation for what you're requesting — work on describing the real problem.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: I edited the question, which describes what I am trying to do, does that help?

Comment: Theoretically you can read the file one character at a time, and compare each character read to a value. That way you don't need an array or a `strchr` call. But it will likely be slow on a large file. But what are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: `int look_for = 'c'; int look_cnt = 0; int n = 4; int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { if (c == look_for) { if (++look_cnt == n) { printf("Got %dth occurence of %c\n", look_cnt, look_for); break; } } }`?  You can decide how you handle the character found and character not found scenarios.  This doesn't use an array (at least not visibly; the I/O system is using an array behind the scenes).  OTOH, it doesn't use address arithmetic either.  OTOOH (on the other, other hand), using address arithmetic without an array doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ Bo Persson: I edited my question, I hope that helps?

Comment: @AMD : No you _changed_ the question - after it already had an answer.  The you asked a new question in a comment.  SO is not a discussion forum.  I had no problem with the original question personally.

Comment: @ Clifford: I am very sorry, but, this is what I am really trying to do. Find the position of a particular character within a text file, without using an array and function strchr.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to read the file into an array and use `strchr`.  What problem do you think you're avoiding by attempting to do it differently?

Comment: @ dbush: I was only trying to imagine if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in an operating system that supports memory mapped files.  This includes Windows and POSIX operating systems such as Linux.

In POSIX it is done using [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html); there is example code in the documentation.

For Windows there is an [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) for for memory mapped files.  Again, sample code is included in the documentation.

Comment: Note that this is a direct answer to the original question which has subsequently been changed.  This answer may no longer be an answer to the current question.